# Can I get an Oxford English spellchecking dictionary?

Tags: spell-checking

I quite like Oxford spelling. This is British/International English spelling, but preferring *-ize* endings to *-ise*. It has the language tag `en-GB-oed`. Is this supported by the spellchecker in Ubuntu?

Comment: Doubt it. The OED is not free. COED with wine has a platinum rating https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3821 but that is not native... Best you'll get is probably http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/text/aspell-en (aspell-en).

Comment: It's not the OED I want, just a spellchecking dictionary in Oxford spelling.

Comment: I know I know. But a spellchecker would be based on the OED (I doubt someone is willing to create a complete new spell checker just for Oxford English :) )

Comment: Oxford spelling is the standard for many international organizations, including ISO, the UN, and the EU, so such dictionaries probably exist somewhere.